# How to ignore files with extension BAK using subversion plugin with Netbeans 7.4?

Tags: netbeans-7

I keep seeing auto generated back-up files when viewing differences between my project and the repository. How can I have the files with the extension *.BAK removed from the list? It's cluttering the view, and the possibility of committing the file occurs from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Added to the end

```
|.*.bak
```

to the Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files > Ignored Files Pattern